# Implementing AppAuth for Outlook API

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, outlook-api, appauth

The [Outlook API tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/ios-tutorial) is using this [p2OAuth2 library](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2) for OAuth2 authentication purpose and further API calls. But can we change the authentication library to [AppAuth-iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS)? I have been using this for Google account integration and found it quiet useful and understandable.

I tried integrating AppAuth for Outlook, and login was successful. After that, I don't know how to implement the same for the APIs part i.e. for Calendar/Mail API.